# How to filter array properties of object?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object that looks like this:

```
myObj = {

    1: 
    [
                {
                "name"  : "ringo",
                "passed": true,
                "level" : 2
                },
                {
                "name"  : "paul",
                "passed": true,
                "level" : 3
                },
                {
                "name"  : "john",
                "passed": false,
                "level" : 4
                },
                {
                "name"  : "george",
                "passed": true,
                "level" : 1
                },
    ],

    2: 
    [
                {
                "name"  : "ringo",
                "passed": true,
                "level" : 2
                },
                {
                "name"  : "paul",
                "passed": true,
                "level" : 3
                },
                {
                "name"  : "john",
                "passed": false,
                "level" : 4
                },
                {
                "name"  : "george",
                "passed": true,
                "level" : 1
                },
    ],
```

}

How do I filter myObj maintaining the myObj structure (ie.keys (1,2) and nested array) and returning the array objects that pass two tests, passed = true and level > 3?

Comment: This is not valid object literal syntax, which would use `:` not `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `_.mapObject` to maintain your key structure, then filter the arrays.

```
var result = _.mapObject(myObj,d=> _.filter(d,k=> k.passed && k.level > 3))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ro4p4kya/

Note that your provided object returns zero results.